# Trying to make a button in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have never coded before so i dont know much, i watched this youtube video on how to make a js button [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w899x2c3aYU)

```
<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:1202px;"
<input type="image" src="images/login.png"
onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/loginpressed.png';" 
onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/login.png';" />
</div>
```

i can see that the code works in dreamweaver, but for somereason, others cannot see it on the [website](http://thecakeisa.li/other/friends/lucas/bluestone2.html#)

Comment: Use a absolute address for your picture like: http://placekitten.com/20/20 to find the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a `>` after `<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:1202px;"`. Because of that, the button is now part of your `div`'s declaration.

B.t.w. You can achieve a similar result by using another element than `input type=image`, like a `span` or `div` or an actual link element (`a href`) and apply some CSS to give it a different background image. For instance:

HTML:

```
<span class="button" onclick="alert('clicked');">Caption</span>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(normalstate.png);
}
.button:hover {
  background-image: url(hoverstate.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that path to your images not found at other place.